# Laravel Test Case to check one element inside a JSON output

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpunit, laravel-5.7

I have the following controller on my `Laravel` application:

```
class ProjectController extends Controller {
    ...
    public function index() {
        $projects = Project::where('is_completed', false)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->withCount(['tasks' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('is_completed', false);
            }])->get();
        return response()->json($projects);
    }
    ...
}
```

which is referenced by the following route:

```
Route::get('projects', 'ProjectController@index');
```

When I go to the url: `http://localhost:8000/api/projects` I get:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Project 02 Title",
        "description": "Project 02 Description",
        "is_completed": 0,
        "created_at": "2018-10-13 16:23:28",
        "updated_at": "2018-10-13 16:23:28",
        "tasks_count": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Project 01 Title",
        "description": "Project 01 Description",
        "is_completed": 0,
        "created_at": "2018-10-13 16:22:52",
        "updated_at": "2018-10-13 16:22:52",
        "tasks_count": 0
    }
]
```

Also, I have the following test file:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class ProjectTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testExample()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');
        // this is not working:
        // $response->assertJson([ 0 => [ 'name' => 'Project 02 Title' ] ]);
    }
}
?>
```

What I want to do on `testExample()` is to check if the `name` member of the first element on the output array (in `JSON` format) has the string value: `Project 02 Title`.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the exact array element you're looking for, you can test individual attributes; for example:

```php
$json = $reponse->json();
$this->assertSame('Project 02 Title', $json[0]['name']);
```

Or in case you want to test the JSON structure you can use:

```php
$response->assertJsonFragment([
   'name' => 'Project 02 Title'
]);
```

Comment: Not a useful approach if you don't know the index that you're testing for. `assertExactJson` and `assertSame` test for an exact match, not a partial one. Editing to make it more helpful.

Answer (score -2):

Check your test again, you are not visiting the right endpoint:

```
$response = $this->get('/');
```

That should probably look more like this:

```
$response = $this->get('/api/projects');
```

Your test should work, it looks okay.